# Showing a Title and an Image Into the Table Header

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uitableview

I am trying to show into the header of my UITableViewController a title and under it an image illustrating the title. The next code (written into the viewDidLoad method) shows only the image, and this image over the rest of the table sections. How I can fix it to do what I want?

```
// Creates a header view.
UIView *containerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 60)] autorelease];
UILabel *headerLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 300, 40)] autorelease];
headerLabel.text = self.name;
headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

GRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 109.0f);
UIImageView *headerImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageRect];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.imagePath];
[headerImage setImage:image];
headerImage.opaque = YES;

[containerView addSubview:headerLabel];
[containerView addSubview:headerImage];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = containerView;
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adjust the views' frames accordingly. The container view's frame must be tall enough to contain the label and image view, and the image view's y coordinate must be set so that it is positioned below the label. The frame rects you are using in your code do not match.

Comment: Sorry Ole but I am an objective-c newbie. Can you link or post me an example?

Comment: Newbie or not, you have to understand what the arguments of `CGRectMake()` mean. Just play a little with the values.

Comment: OK. It works fine now. Thank you Ole. Just playing with the axes everything is solved.